# UPDATE PostgreSQL in vercel 'Ran query successfully' but nothing change

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, next.js, vercel

```
try {
    await sql`
      UPDATE tasks
      SET start = ${start}, endtime = ${endtime}
      WHERE task_id = ${id}
    `;
} catch (error) {
    return { message: "Database Error: Failed to Update task." };
}
```

This code does not return any error but nothing change in my database

When I want to update my data with inline query in vercel :

[image]

It shows query successfully, but nothing changes in my data.

I tried several different solutions, but nothing worked.

Comment: This is generally an indication that  either 1) The transaction was not committed and so the changes did not persist or 2) It was not committed and you are looking at the table from a database session different from the one the update was done in so the second session does not see the uncommitted changes.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), but - **no images**.  Finally, verify your `id` actually exists. Attempting to `update` a non-existing  row **does not** raise an exception.

Comment: *"No rows returned for the query"* means it was successful in the sense that it just didn't raise an exception. My guess is that if you run a `select * from tasks where task_id='88ae2076-88fe-4e6c-b08b-cf41e828cbca';` you just won't find that task because it isn't there. You probably need to go back and find why you're trying to update something that's not there - are you getting the wrong `task_id` from somewhere, or maybe the task is is valid but just wasn't committed yet, so it's not yet available to be updated? Maybe something's wiping it or changing the id?

Comment: If the `task_id` is a uuid saved as text, this condition might not be matching the row due to different capitalisation, leading/trailing whitespace, redundant quotes left as a part of the value, etc.